# Pre-populate form fields based on form input from query

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have input form fields that I want to pre-populate when I type in for example an order # in one of the input boxes. I have successfully wrote the query and outputted it successfully by doing a cfdump. however, I can't figure out how I would auto populate these fields based on what I put in for the order number in the form text field for it? If I put the variables from the query that I prepared into the `value`, it'll pre-populate the form fields but I want the form fields to update based on what I put in for the order #?

Would I have to use JavaScript in order to accomplish this?

**Here are my Input forms.**

```
<label for="ordernum">Order #</label>
<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="">
<label for="companyname">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" name="companyname" value="">
<label for="resident">Resident</label>
<input type="text" name="resident" value="">  
<label for="complexname">Complex Name</label>
<input type="text" name="complexname" value="">
<label for="suitenum">Suite #</label>
<input type="text" name="suitenum" value="">
```

Here is my query

```
<cfquery name="testForm" datasource="randomData"> 
SELECT [COMPANY NAME] AS COMPANYNAME, [RESIDENT], [COMPLEX NAME] AS 
COMPLEXNAME, [SUITE##] AS SUITE, [ORDER##] AS ORDER
FROM tests.DB
WHERE [ORDER##] = 112211
</cfquery>
```

What I tried initially was wrapping those form input fields into a cfoutput query and assigning the variable to the `value` input field but thats pre-populating it I want the form information to update. based on what I put in for the order number field.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ajax call is the option without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ is your best bet. On the third keystroke on the ordernum field, you retrieve the query results with ajax. I'd keep it simple with tab-separated-values. You then fill in the fields with each column in that data set.

```
<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="" id="search">
<script>
$('#search').keyup( getResults );
function getResults(){
  myVal = $('#search').val() ;
  if (myVal.length < 3) {
    $('#list').html('');
  } else {
    $.ajax({
       url: './search.cfm?search='+myVal,
       success: function(data) {
           // fill in the fields with the data
       },
       dataType: 'html',
      timeout: 1000,
      error: function(x, t, m) {
         if(t==="timeout") {
          alert("Something went wrong.");
         } else {
           alert(t);
         }
       }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```